# "You must be logged in to talk" is unreadable on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, chat, design

If you enter a chat room without logging in, the box for typing a message is replaced with "You must be [logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackoverflow.com%2frooms%2f41570%2fso-close-vote-reviewers) to talk.  See the [faq](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information."

This is how it looks on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), with black text on a light gray background:

[image]

However, on [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com), it looks like this, with black text on a dark blue background:

[image]

This is really difficult to read.  Can this please be fixed?