# Bad combination of colors for text and background on Sign up button

Tags: bug, design, sign-up

Just open MSE (or any other SE site) in private mode to see the ugly color-combination:

> [image: Sign up]

Same for the achivements-popup.

BTW don't forget about long standing [colors issue in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279611/339911).

Comment: Probably related/same issue/possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327546/hidden-left-nav-looks-weird-blue-linkish-design

Comment: Just a thought, maybe we shouldn't invite people who have no other Stack Exchange accounts to sign up on Meta? Seems like not having a button on this site could decrease the number of people who get lost and ask random questions here.

Comment: @Stormblessed this issue affects **any** SE site, not only Big Meta.

Comment: Oh, that was just a random idea I had

Comment: @Stormblessed I actually think that's a great idea, I vote for making that a request.

Comment: @Matthew writing a request for it now :-)

Comment: @Matthew [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328922/399694)