# Bounty amount on reputation tab hardly readable

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, design, bounties

Today, a bounty was awarded to [one of my answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327208/295232) (thanks @gnat); when I visited my [reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=reputation) I noticed that the amount is hardly readable since it's green text on a blue background:

[image]

Can that be changed (back?*) to white text please?

*<sub>: I'm sure somebody would've noticed it unless it was a very recent change...</sub>

(Tested on macOS Mojave, latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.)

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 Pro, latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, can reproduced.

Comment: Fully agree, kinda looks 'dirty' and blurs the text with the background..

Comment: Looks like some dev forgot some class.

Comment: @ShadowWizard *class*ical mistake. And now I'll see myself out.

Comment: Related color issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327846/339911

Comment: Cannot reproduce with latest Firefox. Possibly fixed, @Glorfindel?

Comment: Still happening for me (Firefox 67.0, macOS 10.14.5)

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Why is the color of a bounty number in the “Reputation” tab dark green (not white)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385529/4642212).

Comment: Just noticed this happening on SFF so the issue is still present. I did look through my SO profile to find a bounty and it had white text so it has potentially been fixed for SO only. See [my SFF report](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12593/58193).

Comment: I think it'd be worth pointing out that some colour blind people might not even be able to see the text as it currently.

Comment: Happens on chrome/macOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in the CSS after all, due to the inspection. It felt like, as a website enthusiast, that the CSS that references the text in the positive rep which is green is overriding the text inside the special case for bounties which is white to avoid what happened today.

After I inspected, turns out it is the case, and the problem is now figured out. The text for normal positive rep is overriding the text for the special bounty award.

I also saw it on StackOverflow. I was going to post the bug on Meta SO but then I decided to inspect it to see what's going on.