# Bounty text color is awful

Tags: bug, reputation, design, bounties

Green text `color`! Are you serious! It used to be white for sure.

Could be found in the reputation tab - for example, I browsed [this dear user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene?tab=reputation).

[image]

Comment: Absolutely unreadable, actually.

Comment: This is a beautiful blue rectangle. Is there something supposed to be inside of it?

Comment: @John the number's playing hide-n-seek with you, be careful

Comment: I guess there's a couple of design bugs left waiting for me to come and find them...

Comment: Fun fact: the text is actually _more_ readable with deuteranopia than with typical eyes. And it's still readable with full color blindness.

Comment: @Rob, wow srsly, two months not fixed yet? it's just about editing the stylesheet a bit... weird

Comment: Why was this question closed as [a dupe of a question that has not yet been answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328559/bounty-amount-on-reputation-tab-hardly-readable)

Comment: @Namaste because it's the same bug report and because the OP apparently agreed with the dupe-closure.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, @MonicaCellio ...