# Don’t tell people with no account at every possible point to join Meta

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

We get a lot of crappy questions on Meta from people who don’t in any way understand it, most of the time thinking they’re on Stack Overflow. If we want to decrease the chance of this, **what if we didn’t have all these “sign up” buttons everywhere on Meta for those without any Stack Exchange Network accounts?** If I go to Meta in private browsing, it looks just like the other sites, with the “sign up” button in the top right (on the mobile site). If we got rid of that, way less people would sign up here with no clue what Stack Exchange was.

Comment: I support this idea, but I believe Stack Exchange will take all the new users it can get. As far as I know it's not a non=profit organization after all.

Comment: @Matthew well I doubt Meta is very profitable compared to the other sites on the Network like SO.

Comment: Aren't they all part of the same company in the end?

Comment: @Matthew Yeah, but I mean new Meta users aren’t something they’d particularly make a lot of money off compared to users who join SO or the like. Meta shouldn’t have much data to take, compared to sites like SF (with movies you might be interested in, per se) and SO; the last site is very, very big and I believe SO is the only site from SE that makes money off of non-data things, so it’s the most profitable site probably.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter. They will click "ask question" and then be forced to create an account in order to continue asking whatever off-topic mess they were about to post. I think this is more an issue of people just not realizing what this site is for.

Comment: Would a better title for this post possibly be: 'Hide the "Sign Up" button on MSE for users without a StackExchange account on any other site'?